# Implementation of IDataObject::SetData(ref FORMATETC formatetc, ref STGMEDIUM stgmedium, bool param) in C#

Tags: implementation

I've already spent hours to find answeres how to do this, and I didn't find any responses on othere forums. Could anybody tell me please how to form Dataobject from these to structs: FORMATETC, STGMEDIUM ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to get the same information but there's no good example of OLE Copy/Paste. Here's a link that can help: [Implementing IDataObject](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/implementing-idataobject). Note that this is in C++. See the MSDN link for C# version.

Hope this helps. I've also posted as similar OLE copy question on MSDN which might get answered so I am posting the link here: [MSDN Question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/e09287f4-95e2-4393-92d6-08324c719a93/how-to-copy-data-to-ole-clipboard-that-can-be-pasted-as-embedded-object#c16e18c8-ff88-4650-aebc-cf612082bb21)